# I cannot access Portainer UI on the browser

Tags: docker, portainer

I have a docker swarm set up with Portainer running - when I ssh in and run docker ps the results are

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS
                NAMES
abb69573d785   portainer/agent:2.18.3          "./agent"                11 seconds ago   Up 4 seconds
                portainer_agent.tdh6gefsejl615h9jmu2b0ukg.kylfewi01q6yrmwhz4pbxfow3
0e04c9c26d60   portainer/portainer-ce:2.18.3   "/portainer -H tcp:/…"   18 seconds ago   Up 11 seconds   8000/tcp, 9000/tcp, 9443/tcp   portainer_portainer.1.a46l4cnv0wpbnh3l9skk3pxdk
```

However, when I visit http://IPAddress:9000 it does not connect and my browser gives me a connection timed out error.

I have checked that the ports are open and confirmed that this is not a firewall issue.

Comment: Are you by any chance running Linux with selinux module? (Fedora f.e)

Comment: @mouchin777 No, this is on Ubuntu